# How to upload image to web page in Saucelabs test by Selenium in c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, saucelabs

I must upload any image to web page to create online shop to move on test. I have to click on button for uploading after that I have to give directory of the file, but I can't give local directory because test runs on VM on Saucelabs. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `LocalFileDetector` class. Your code will look something like this:

```
// WARNING!! Untested code written from memory, without benefit of an IDE.
// May not work exactly correctly or even compile without modification. 
// Assume driver is a properly instantiated IWebDriver object, which is
// to be used with a remote service (including SauceLabs or similar).
IAllowsFileDetection fileDetectionDriver = driver as IAllowsFileDetection;
fileDetectionDriver.FileDetector = new LocalFileDetector();

IWebElement fileElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("idOfFileInputElement"));
fileElement.SendKeys(@"C:\path\to\local.file");
```

By setting the file detector, the `SendKeys` method will first upload the file from your local system to the remote machine on which the code is actually running. Then `SendKeys` will set the file in the `<input>` element, using the local file path on the remote machine.